# Questions to expect when interviewing for teaching-focused faculty position

Tags: job-search, tenure-track, interview

I'm going to interview for a teaching-focused position in a couple of weeks, and I was wondering what kind of questions to expect.

I know there are plenty of resources on what to expect in a standard tenure-track interview. However, all the ones I found are geared towards research-focused positions, where teaching is an afterthought at best.

Comment: I guess it would depend on the individual factors. Also based on your previous experience. Giving some general answer would be difficult.

Comment: I do not think that this question is appropriate for this site because it has many answers and depends on discipline and country.  In my experience, it is quite common to get questions like:  Why do you want this job?  How do you teach?  What do you do about diversity?  What courses can you teach?  Usually the questions are like that, but with lots of extra words.

Comment: Make sure that you have some familiarity with phrases such as cooperative learning, active learning, flipped classroom, etc. Maybe look though the teaching statements, class syllabi, etc. of faculty in the department you're interviewing at, along with those of faculty from closely related departments, to see what types of teaching practices seem to be popular there. Be prepared to describe what you've tried, your successes and failures, how you motivate apathetic students, how you deal with classes in which some students can hardly keep up while others are bored at the slow pace, etc.

Comment: After your job talk, they might ask if any of what you presented is something an undergrad math major could work on with you. When I was an undergrad at a small liberal arts college, they asked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that this is a teaching focused college or university. Some top schools have such teaching positions, but they are not on the tenure track (Duke, CMU, Stanford, ...). As such, your interviewers will probably be very experienced teachers.

The questions may vary, but the core of the exploration will be to discover what if any *teaching philosophy* you have. There are many aspects to this.

At one extreme (perhaps) is a philosophy that you must *teach every student*. *Sink or swim* is something like the antipode. (Other dimensions are possible, I suspect. Precise exposition vs. insight generating lectures, say.)

Also related to this is to explore your understanding of how students learn. This understanding (or lack of it) will likely affect your teaching philosophy, of course.

Questions may be detailed, but are looking, primarily, to see what you think the true nature of the job is. How you deal with problems, with diversity, with conflict, with individual needs, etc. all lead to a judgement about the nature of the job in your view.

Part of that is to determine how open you are to improving and advancing in the art of teaching itself. The details of the questions are less important than what they reveal about you and your relationship to students.

And, in some fields, it is also important to try to determine how your own knowledge of the field is likely to grow as the field changes, and how you might adapt teach to those changes.

Note also that professors with primarily teaching positions are normally required to produce some "scholarly output" or actual research. Don't neglect that. It may be very important for advancement to be known as active in your field.

---

Personal note: After forty or so years in the saddle, teaching at a very broad range of colleges and a very broad range of students, I have a pretty sophisticated view and have formally examined the question of "how to teach." But "early me" would probably fail to pass muster on questions asked by "current me".

I've learned that you can be simultanesly both kind/understanding and strict/demanding, for example. You don't need to "teach to the middle". You can be flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Buffy's answer is quite good.  I'd like to add one additional nugget.

When I am interviewing a candidate for a Teaching Faculty position, I also ask about how you go about learning about teaching.  An amazing proportion of candidates don't seem to have ever thought about their processes for studying how to teach.  Part of that, of course, is that many universities don't do a great job of training PhD students in how to teach.

So, spend some time thinking about how you have learned and what you will do to continue to learn pedagogical topics and ideas.

I once had a candidate who didn't know what "pedagogical" meant.  Make sure you understand that word.